# How to print a scaled and rotated image

Tags: c#, wpf

**Background**

I have got a WPF user control that displays an image, which can be rotated and zoomed with multi touch gestures:

```
<UserControl>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behavior:MultitouchTransformBehavior MaximumScale="100.0" MinimumScale="0.01"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
</UserControl>
```

This works fine. I also can print the original source picture using the `PrintDocument` class.

**Question**

Now I'd like to print the image as the user sees it on screen, i.e. in its zoomed and rotated state.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
   public static void CreateBitmapFromVisual(Visual target, string fileName)
    {
        if (target == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            return;
        }

        Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);

        RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((Int32)bounds.Width, (Int32)bounds.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

        using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(target);
            context.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size));
        }

        renderTarget.Render(visual);
        PngBitmapEncoder bitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        bitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));
        using (Stream stm = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            bitmapEncoder.Save(stm);
        }
    }
```

I have taken it from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df4db537-a201-4ab4-bb7e-db38a5c2b6e0/wpf-equivalent-of-winforms-controldrawtobitmap?forum=wpf) when I had same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can confirm that it generates an image file. In my case this is still the _original_ image, not the scaled/rotated version. I don't know how to integrate your function into my user control.

Comment: Ok, it works. Also check this [code](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/03/taking-wpf-screenshots/)